# Writing out evaluated cellcontent to file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Hi like to do the following:

My cell contains:

```
%%writefile foo.txt
a = 'bar'
print(a)
```

After evaluation of that cell I like foo.txt to look like:

```
a = 'bar'
bar
```

But can I trigger the evaluation of the content of the cell before it's written out?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. But why would you want to do that ?

Comment: I've found a work around using `!echo {a}`. As for why have a look at http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dietmarw/M_S_L/blob/master/Resources/yEd/GeneratePDF.ipynb Though I would still be interested in a more Ipythonic way :-)